# get an empty SpatialPolygonsDataFrame via subset?

Tags: r, spatial, r-maptools, r-sp

I'm looking to subset a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame by an attribute, but I want to allow it to return an empty SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

If we are to treat objects of type SpatialPolygonsDataFrame like data.frames, as discussed [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2007-October/002701.html), we should be able to get and work with empty objects.

I'm interested because I want to incorporate this into a function that may try to subset by an attribute that will essentially pick no features.

```
owd <- getwd() 
setwd(system.file("shapes", package = "maptools")) 
library(maptools) 
nc90 <- readShapeSpatial("co37_d90") 
setwd(owd)

nc90@data[nc90@data$AREA>0.15,]               # returns data.frame
bigctys <- nc90[nc90@data$AREA>0.15,]         # SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
nc90@data[nc90@data$AREA>0.25,]               # returns empty data.frame
bigestctys <- nc90[nc90@data$AREA>0.25,]      # ERROR
```

Is there a way to make this work?  If not, is there a way to initalize an empty SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object? The future actions I want to perform on such an object involve over plotting on an existing map, so I'd like the image to be produced anyways, even if blank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you can't. This is somewhat inconsistent, as for `SpatialPointsDataFrame` objects you can:

```
library(sp)
demo(meuse, ask = FALSE)
x = meuse[F,]
```

although with warnings; also, `validObject(x)` returns `FALSE`, so they are intended to be not allowed!

It's a bit abstract what such objects should represent, but I can see the analogy with `data.frame` objects with zero rows: it is useful that they can exist.